# Subfields of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

I want to find the intermediate extension of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$ over $\Bbb Q$. And for each subfield, I need to find what is the correspondence subgroup of $(\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z_8)^*$ that fixes the field.

The following is what I have tried so far:

1. Find the degree of $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_8):\Bbb Q]$.

I calculated the minimial polynomial by the definition of cyclotomic polynomial. It is $x^4+1$.

2. Knowing this, I find the basis of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)/\Bbb Q$ is: $1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\zeta^3$.
3. $Gal(\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)/\Bbb Q)=\lbrace \sigma_1,\sigma_2, \sigma_3,\sigma_4\rbrace$
   where

$\sigma_1:\zeta\mapsto \zeta$

$\sigma_2:\zeta\mapsto \zeta^3$

$\sigma_3:\zeta\mapsto \zeta^5$

$\sigma_4:\zeta\mapsto \zeta^7$

4. I want to determine the fixed field via the basis:

$\sigma_3(a+b\zeta+c\zeta^2+d\zeta^3)=a+b\zeta^5+c\zeta^2+d\zeta^7$.

So $\sigma_3$ fixes $\Bbb Q(\zeta^2)=\Bbb Q(i)$.

$\sigma_2(a+b\zeta+c\zeta^2+d\zeta^3)=a+b\zeta^3+c\zeta^6+d\zeta$.

So $\sigma_2$ fixes $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is of form $b=d,c=0$. Which is $\Bbb Q(i\sqrt{2})$.

Now $\sigma_4(a+b\zeta+c\zeta^2+d\zeta^3)=a+b\zeta^7+c\zeta^6+d\zeta^5$.

I am confused, how could I deal with that?

Thanks for help!

Comment: $\zeta^4=-1$, so $\sigma_4(a+b\zeta+c\zeta^2+d\zeta^3) = a-b\zeta^3-c\zeta^2-d\zeta$, so $a+b\zeta+c\zeta^2+d\zeta^3$ is fixed by $\sigma_4$ iff
$b=-d, \text{ and } c=0$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Thanks I see it! But may I please ask how can see that this number is $\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\sigma_4^2$ is the identity, any $\alpha+\sigma_4(\alpha)$
lies in the fixed field of $\alpha$. In particular,
$\zeta+\sigma_4(\zeta)=\zeta+\zeta^7=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}
=e^{\pi i/4}+e^{-\pi i/4}=2\cos(\pi/4)$. What is that?

Comment: It is exactly $\sqrt{2}$. But may I please ask why does it come from the fact that $\sigma^2_4=id$?

Comment: @PropositionX If $\sigma^2=1$ then $\sigma(a+\sigma(a))=\sigma(a)+\sigma^2(a)=\sigma(a)+a$: $a+\sigma(a)$ is fixed by $\sigma$.

Comment: I think it is a more elegant argument then mine. Thanks a lot!